# Binding combo box to itemsource from main window resource property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind this combo:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StudentStudyPointsList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>
> 'StudentStudyPointsList' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow'
>    (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=StudentStudyPointsList;
>
> DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'ComboBox'
>    (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

The property is publicly defined in the main view model:

```
public List<StudyPointItem> StudentStudyPointsList { get; set; }
```

And the main window has this DataContext:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:OCLMEditorModelView/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

How do I get the Combo to bind the itemsource correctly?

Comment: Your ` AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}` is most likely of type `Window` instead of `MainWindow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```